# In Ruby why does nil.id return 4?

Tags: ruby

This is has been bugging me for quite some time.

```
>> nil.id
(irb):2: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 4
```

Why would nil.id be 4? (or nil.object_id if you want to be picky about deprecations)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is because nil is an object created when the language initializes, and that object's id happens to always be 4.

For more information about why the id happens to be 4, see [this](http://neeraj.name/blog/articles/662-why-the-id-of-nil-is-4-in-ruby) blog post.

Comment: I'm a Ruby Facebook programmer and it happens that 4 is also Mark Zuckerber ID on Facebook. This lead me to the weirdest bug ever... ;-)

Comment: This is not true for me its "8"
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> nil.object_id 
=> 8
irb(main):002:0> 
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]

Comment: Cool, then the internals has changed between 2009 and 2013. Just shows never to depend in implementation details ;)

Answer (score 12):

I'd always assumed it was a cool easter egg: In Japan 4 is the number of death.

Answer (score 4):

It happens because the id of every object had to somehow be represented in the C Ruby interpreter. Numbers got mapped to (number*2)+1, truthiness got 0, falseness got 2 and nil had 4 left. It´s just a weird implementation issue or leaky abstraction. You shouldn't worry about it unless you want to write a Ruby interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this in irb you are getting 4

```
irb
>> NIL.id
(irb):7: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 4
```

In ruby Japanese people set on nil methods call it returns 4 it's language standard that they set 4 as "Dangerous" OR "Death"