# Called id for nil in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In development mode:

```
nil.id
=> "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"
```

In production mode:

```
nil.id
=> 4
```

Why?

Answer (score 11):

Look for the line that says the following in your environments configs:

```
# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true # or false in production.rb
```

This is to prevent you from calling methods on `nil` while in development mode. I guess they disabled it for performance reasons in production.

And `nil` is a singleton object in ruby, that's why its `id` will be 4 no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Your development.rb evironment has the following line:

```
 config.whiny_nils = true
```

Which will log an error when you try to call a method on `nil`.  `nil`'s id is 4 because [it is an object which happens to have an id of 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553449/in-ruby-why-does-nil-id-return-4)

Answer (score 2):

Code of method `NilClass#id` has good explanation:

```
# NilClass#id exists in Ruby 1.8 (though it is deprecated). Since +id+ is a fundamental
# method of Active Record models NilClass#id is redefined as well to raise a RuntimeError
# and warn the user. She probably wanted a model database identifier and the 4
# returned by the original method could result in obscure bugs.
#
# The flag <tt>config.whiny_nils</tt> determines whether this feature is enabled.
# By default it is on in development and test modes, and it is off in production
# mode.
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c76eb1106dc82bb0e3cc50498383d6f992da4fb/activesupport/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb#L19

Answer (score 1):

Whiny nils are only reported during development mode (look into your config files).

> "Whiny nils" is the Rails term for putting warnings into the log
>   whenever a method is invoked on a nil value, with (hopefully) helpful
>   information about which sort of object you might have been trying to
>   use.