# Assign user_id with http basic authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I switched to http basic authorization in my API for now to make testing easier, but now I can't get a user_id... Here's the code in my ThingController that worked with devise:

```
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
    @thing.user_id = current_user.id
    @thing.save
    if @thing.save
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This now gives me the following error:

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

and it references the line

```
@thing.user_id = current_user.id
```

I'm not sure how to assign a user_id to my Things when creating.. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at at the following answer and see if that helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554783/called-id-for-nil-in-rails-3

Comment: I understand that nil's id == 4.  That's not my question.  I am asking how not to assign nil's id to my thing.user_id.  Right now it's not pointing to anything.  I need to find a way to save the current user's id when logged in using basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem you got an answer.  I faced the same issue.  I found this wiki of use
 [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)
where you state your login in the following method

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
    some_class_url(session[:some_class_id])
  end
```

which allows you to do the things you need on the targeted action