# what does calling object_id on a class definition do?

Tags: ruby

I'm playing around with some ruby code and doing something like:

```
1.9.3-p392 :012 > class Mx; self; end.object_id
 => 70263149976460 
1.9.3-p392 :013 > class Mx; end.object_id
 => 4
```

I think that the first example is returning a real reference to that class as the code is executed but what is happening in the second example? What is 4? It's interesting that it returns NilClass if

```
1.9.3-p392 :017 > class Mx; end.class
 => NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Mx; end` returns `nil`, so that's what you observed.

On the contrary `class Mx; self; end` returns class `Mx` itself.

Comment: @timpone It's the object_id of nil.  Try nil.object_id

Comment: ok cool, thx,  I see that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553449/in-ruby-why-does-nil-id-return-4

Answer (score 3):

A class definition is an expression. All expressions evaluate to a value. For:

`class Foo; end` that value is `nil`.

Within a class definition (and other blocks) ruby 
returns the value for the last expression in the block. If the block is empty the value returned is nil.

`class Foo; "BLAH"; end # => "BLAH"`

Here `self` is a reference to the class introduced by `class Foo`.

`class Foo; self; end # => Foo`

`nil` is a singleton "object", that has a `.class` => `NilClass`.

And "4" is the `.object_id` of `nil`. In your interpreter you can do `nil.object_id`. BTW the object ids are implementation specific, you cannot rely on `nil.object_id == 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Class definition expressions evaluate to the value of the last expression inside of the class definition. In the second case, there is *nothing* in the class definition, so the class definition evaluates to Ruby's representation of nothingness, which is `nil`.

In the first case, the last (and only) expression inside the class definition is `self`, which is a special pseudo-variable corresponding to the current object, and in a class definition that is the class object itself. (Remember, classes are objects just like any other object.)