# Why does rails have 'which would mistakenly be 4' in the Called ID for nil error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When you call find with a nil ID, or when you try to access a relational object that doesn't exist, this error gets thrown:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

What is the 'which would mistakenly be 4' about? It seems so odd/irrelevant to 99.9% of the nil ID errors people encounter. Is it a holdover from an old era bug? Why is it in there?

Comment: Does answer it, but in my defense to the downvoters it is a different question (as Ruby no longer returns 4 when `nil.id` is called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ActiveSupport's [`NilClass`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.15/classes/NilClass.html) extension:

> `#id` exists in Ruby 1.8 (though it is deprecated). Since `id` is a fundamental method of Active Record models `#id` is redefined as well to
>   raise a `RuntimeError` and warn the user. She probably wanted a model
>   database identifier and the 4 returned by the original method could
>   result in obscure bugs.
>
> The flag `config.whiny_nils` determines whether this feature is enabled.
>   By default it is on in development and test modes, and it is off in
>   production mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per [In Ruby why does nil.id return 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553449/in-ruby-why-does-nil-id-return-4) -- Ruby *used* to return 4 when `.id` was called on `nil`; so Rails, when trying to find by `nil` throws the error message stating that if you were to try to call `.find` with `nil`, you'd be finding `4`.