# Understanding how nested routes work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-routes

I am a bit confused.
This is my routes file:

[image]

When I try this, the link will not be as expected (cl is my checklist):

```
<%= page_checklist_path(cl) %>
```

The renders string of the link as:

```
/pages/31/checklists/4
```

But it should be

```
/pages/4/checklists/31
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Any reason why you do not use [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)?

Comment: That was new to me until just now and therefore I don't know yet whether this will bring me an advantage and whether it will solve my problem. I would first have to read up on the subject of shallow nesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using nested routes like that then you have to provide both instances as arguments. See [creating paths and URLs from objects](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) in the Rails guides. That means you need to call your route helper like this:

```
<%= page_checklist_path(page, checklist) %> # or
<%= page_checklist_path(checklist.page, checklist) %>
```

If you want to avoid that I suggest using [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting). The ID of the checklist is unique in your database anyway, therefore the page ID is not really needed when nesting routes.

Fun fact: The `4` in the URL from your example is not the page's ID (because you didn't provide a page at all). But [`nil` has the ID `4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553449/in-ruby-why-does-nil-id-return-4) in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, worked fine now.


typical beginner mistake.
That happened to me before, but I didn't consider this case.

I'll take a look at what you wrote last

Comment: @spickermann what I don't understand here is why the code in the question isn't raising a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` and how on earth it ends up coercing `nil` to `4` since `Object#id` was deprechiated and removed  quite some time ago. I also get `nil.object_id == 8` on MRI 3.0.2.